# How to convert RDD to Dataframe Spark 2.4.5 Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm fully a newbie for databricks and spark. I was using data bricks community edition and Spark 2.4.5 cluster. I was trying to modify the code to be run from Spark 1.6.2 to Spark 2.4.5 since in community edition, it's not allowed to create a cluster using Spark 1.6.2. Can someone help me on converting RDD object to Dataframe in Spark 2.4.5?



***CODE***

```
summary = data.select("OrderMonthYear", "SaleAmount").groupBy("OrderMonthYear").sum().orderBy("OrderMonthYear") #.toDF("OrderMonthYear","SaleAmount")
# Convert OrderMonthYear to integer type
#results = summary.map(lambda r: (int(r.OrderMonthYear.replace('-','')), r.SaleAmount)).toDF(["OrderMonthYear","SaleAmount"])
rddData = summary.rdd.map(lambda r: (int(r.OrderMonthYear.replace('-','')), r.SaleAmount))
#rddData1 = rddData.flatMap(lambda x : [(k, x) for k in x.keys()])

# assuming the spark environemnt is set and sc is spark.sparkContext 
schemaPeople = spark.createDataFrame(rddData)
```

The code which was running in Spark 1.6.2 is as bellow

```
#results = summary.map(lambda r: (int(r.OrderMonthYear.replace('-','')), r.SaleAmount)).toDF(["OrderMonthYear","SaleAmount"])
```

The code which i was modified and not working as follows

```
rddData = summary.rdd.map(lambda r: (int(r.OrderMonthYear.replace('-','')), r.SaleAmount))
schemaPeople = spark.createDataFrame(rddData)
```

***An error is issuing when trying to convert RDD to DataFrame in following line***

```
schemaPeople = spark.createDataFrame(rddData)
```

[image]


***ERROR***
[image]

Thank You

***Full detail error***

```
SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 36.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 36.0 (TID 2821, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 480, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 472, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 508, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<command-1212426270091216>", line 6, in <lambda>
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:540)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:659)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:494)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:640)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1541)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:543)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 36.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 36.0 (TID 2821, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 480, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 472, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 508, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<command-1212426270091216>", line 6, in <lambda>
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:540)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:659)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:494)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:640)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1541)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:543)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2362)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2350)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2349)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2349)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2582)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2529)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2517)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:897)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollectResult(limit.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectResult(Dataset.scala:2890)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectResult$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectResult$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2880)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$54.apply(Dataset.scala:3492)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$54.apply(Dataset.scala:3487)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3487)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:2880)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation0(OutputAggregator.scala:149)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation(OutputAggregator.scala:54)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal$$anonfun$getResultBufferInternal$1.apply(PythonDriverLocal.scala:984)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal$$anonfun$getResultBufferInternal$1.apply(PythonDriverLocal.scala:931)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.withInterpLock(PythonDriverLocal.scala:876)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.getResultBufferInternal(PythonDriverLocal.scala:931)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.getResultBuffer(DriverLocal.scala:492)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.com$databricks$backend$daemon$driver$PythonDriverLocal$$outputSuccess(PythonDriverLocal.scala:918)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$6.apply(PythonDriverLocal.scala:364)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$6.apply(PythonDriverLocal.scala:351)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.withInterpLock(PythonDriverLocal.scala:876)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.repl(PythonDriverLocal.scala:351)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:396)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:373)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:275)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:373)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 480, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 472, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 508, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<command-1212426270091216>", line 6, in <lambda>
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:540)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:659)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:494)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:640)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1541)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:543)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got success with following code.

After 8days of findings and help of a great guy at stack overflow("https://stackoverflow.com/users/2451763/sparker0i") together could came up with the following code which did work with Spark 2.4.5 in databricks.

**Aggregate and Convert**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
dataF = data.select("OrderMonthYear", date_format("OrderMonthYear", 'yyyy-MM-dd').alias("dt_format"), "SaleAmount").groupBy("dt_format").sum().orderBy("dt_format").toDF("dt_format", "SaleAmount")

dataF.show()

results = tata.rdd.map(lambda r: (int(r.dt_format.replace('-','')), r.SaleAmount)) 
df = spark.createDataFrame(results,("dt_format", "SaleAmount")) 
display(df)
```

***Convert DataFrame to Features and Labels***

```
#convenience for specifying schema 

from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

meta = df.select("dt_format", "SaleAmount").toDF("dt_format","SaleAmount") meta.show()

rdd1 = meta.rdd.map(lambda r: LabeledPoint(r[1], [r[0]]))

rddtodf=spark.createDataFrame(rdd1,("dt_format","SaleAmount")) display(rddtodf)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: what's tata in results = tata.rdd.map(lambda r: (int(r.dt_format.replace('-','')), r.SaleAmount))? why you just don't use dataF?

Answer (score 1):

I see you have commented out `#.toDF("OrderMonthYear","SaleAmount")` in the first line of your code. What's wrong in that?

Assuming `rddData` is the `RDD` you create after your transformations, you can use `rddData.toDF(["a", "b", "c",....])`. For this to work, you must have knowledge on the columns present in the RDD.

What I would suggest you is to read your data directly as a `DataFrame`. You will have to make changes to your code, but it should be worth it.

---

EDIT 1: Looking at the comments in how you're reading your data, you could directly read the CSV file as a `DataFrame`. You are using:

```
path = 'file:/databricks/driver/CogsleyServices-SalesData-US.csv'
data = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("sep", ",").load(path)
```

You do not need to use the Spark's `SQLContext` to read a CSV. You can directly read a dataframe using a SparkSession.

I just tried it on Spark/Python, and the following code to read a sample csv worked inside Jupyter notebook on my local:

```
spark.read.format("csv").option("header", True).option("delimiter", ",").load(r"C:\Users\Spark\Downloads\boston_housing.csv")
```

Where `spark` is your `SparkSession`.

EDIT 2:

Now I get what you are trying to do. Checking your full error log, we see `TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)`. The problem is in `lambda r: (int(r.OrderMonthYear.replace('-',''))` part. If you do `summary.show()` alone, you will realize that the timestamp contains `-`,  and `:`. Unless you are planning to use this timestamp ever again, I'd suggest you to convert the timestamp of your dataframe to a unix timestamp.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
from pyspark.sql.types import *

summary = data.select("OrderMonthYear", "SaleAmount").groupBy("OrderMonthYear").sum().orderBy("OrderMonthYear").withColumn("unix_timestamp", fn.unix_timestamp(fn.col('OrderMonthYear'), format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

This worked for me.

Comment: ```#.toDF("OrderMonthYear","SaleAmount")```method only works in Spark 1.6.2 cluster. Not in Spark 2.4.5. The same error given. Could not understand why?
Original code that runs in Spark 1.6.2 is as follows,```summary = data.select("OrderMonthYear", "SaleAmount").groupBy("OrderMonthYear").sum().orderBy("OrderMonthYear").toDF("OrderMonthYear","SaleAmount")  <br/>  # Convert OrderMonthYear to integer type
results = summary.map(lambda r: (int(r.OrderMonthYear.replace('-','')), r.SaleAmount)).toDF(["OrderMonthYear","SaleAmount"])```

Comment: Though I use Spark 2.4.5 over Scala, `rdd.toDF(columnlist)` still works in that approach. I don't see why it shouldn't work with Spark/Python. With my experience of Spark/Scala, when you get error like `Job aborted due to...`, there will be additional stacktrace after this. If any of the additional stacktraces contains a `NullPointerException`, that means it is because you're trying to pass an `RDD` (created using an active `SparkSession`/`SqlContext`/something else) within a method (`createDataFrame()`) provided by `SparkSession` (`spark` in your case).

Comment: I couldn't find any NullPointerException in the trace. Full details error is added to the post at the end in a code block. Please find the data variable code that I used in the other comment.

Comment: It's really doesn't matter and a big favor, if you can help me converting that errant code to scalar.
```%sh curl -O 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bsullins/bensullins.com-freebies/master/CogsleyServices-SalesData-US.csv'
path = 'file:/databricks/driver/CogsleyServices-SalesData-US.csv'
data = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("sep", ",").load(path) 
data.cache()
data = data.dropna() 
display(data)```

Comment: Please check Edit 1. There's a better way to read a dataframe from CSV in Spark 2.4.5

Comment: either way that code line works. but issue is happening when I map. It returns an RDD object and when I try to show the RDD object once after converting to a dataframe as used as in next 2 comment.

Comment: ```summary = data.select("OrderMonthYear", "SaleAmount").groupBy("OrderMonthYear").sum().orderBy("OrderMonthYear").toDF("OrderMonthYear","SaleAmount")
results = summary.rdd.map(lambda r: (int(r.OrderMonthYear.replace('-','')), r.SaleAmount))
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([StructField("OrderMonthYear", IntegerType(), False), StructField("SaleAmount", DoubleType(), False)]) ```

Comment: ```df = spark.createDataFrame(results,schema)
df1 = df.toDF("OrderMonthYear","SaleAmount")
display(df1)```

Comment: Please Check Edit 2.

Comment: no luck. I used the same code that you were mentioned. It works. But my questions is not there. its with when I try to show the data using ```diplay(df)``` this is where the error is issuing. Not from any where else. The error log i shared when I run ```display(df)``` function after all code works. can u please check bellow codes in the next 2 comments.

Comment: If `df.show()` works, then `display()` should work as well. If `df.show()` works, then it's not a problem with Spark/Pyspark per se.

Comment: This is the code that issue the error ```from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint  
data = summary.select("unix_timestamp", "SaleAmount").toDF("unix_timestamp","SaleAmount")
rdd1 = data.rdd.map(lambda r: LabeledPoint(r[1], [r[0]]))  
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([StructField("unix_timestamp", IntegerType(), False),
                         StructField("SaleAmount", DoubleType(), False)])
df1=spark.createDataFrame(rdd1,schema)
data1 = df1.select("unix_timestamp", "SaleAmount").toDF("unix_timestamp","SaleAmount")```

Comment: so change the schema to accept nullable. ```schema = StructType([StructField("unix_timestamp", DoubleType(), True),
                         StructField("SaleAmount", DoubleType(), True)])``` Then it shows the data. But all null

Comment: finally got it works. Issue was with the schema used when converting RDD to dataframe.I changed it like this which worked. ```rddtodf=spark.createDataFrame(rdd1,("unix_timestamp","SaleAmount"))``` Thanks for your excellent support. I leaned a lot during the discussion.